# Image to plane not working for me

Tags: image, video

This feature was working then i tried rendering it and planes were blank. I tried adding another different image as plane and it doesn't show at all just a black plane. The video i am trying to add is in documents>blender projects>folder>videos, no idea whats happening or what I've done.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It could be an issue with the codec of the specific video you're using. Try saving the video to a JPG or PNG image sequence and use that instead. You can use the free program Handbrake to save out the images or use a different codec.

Comment: Thanks, i tried  a jpeg and it works but all 3 videos mp4s and avi's all didn't work in cycles but works fine in blender render. My project is made in cycles though, weird problem as it's worked before.

Comment: Looking closer at the node setup, you have a noodle going from the alpha output of the image node to the fac on the mix node. mp4 and avi codecs do not support alpha. Try connecting the diffuse node directly to the material output and see if it renders.

Comment: Actually disregard that last comment, I tested that in 2.79 and even without an alpha channel in the video, it doesn't affect it. Although, I'm having no problems

Comment: thanks for trying, i'm trying it on an old laptop and it works fine but need it to work on my new laptop

Answer (score 1):

First change image source from Movie to Single Image or Image Sequence.

[image]

In Texture viewport shading mode, image texture for displaying must be active at Node Editor.

Just click on it and it should be appeared.

Comment: thanks, Not sure how to do this, i'm a bit lost again, still learning. I'm trying to add a video to a plane, i should have made it clear. I have plane selected and am in texture mode and i think plane is active, still same result.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1:

You want to be in `Material Preview` mode:

[image]

Not in `Solid` mode:

[image]

### Solution 2:

If you want to stay in `viewport shading > solid mode` you can select the image in object mode, then you select `Viewport shading > Color > Texture`:

[image]